# NSDate get a specific day of the week?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I hope this is just a learning curve I'm going through.

I create an arbitrary date.  I want to find the Saturday following the third Friday.

```
    NSLog(@"Date: %@", [date description]);
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSTimeZone *zone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"];
    [calendar setTimeZone:zone];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
    [components setWeekday:6];        // 1 = Sunday ... 7 = Saturday
    [components setWeekdayOrdinal:3]; // 3rd Friday
    resultDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    NSLog(@"Date: %@", [resultDate description]);
```

And the output:

Date: 2010-11-01 05:00:00 GMT

Date: 2010-11-01 05:00:00 GMT

Why?  How can I fix this?

Comment: In the future do not put things such as " I hate insertTechnology here"

Comment: It was sarcasm - it's obvious I have to learn more about it in order to be accustomed to it.  As the statement following it says, 'I hope this is just a learning curve I'm going through.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Change the components to:</strike>

```
(NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit)
```

This works:

```
 NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
 NSLog([today description]);

 NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

 NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:(NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];

 NSDateComponents *componentsToSubtract = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
 [componentsToSubtract setDay: 0 - ([weekdayComponents weekday])];
 [componentsToSubtract setWeekdayOrdinal:([weekdayComponents weekday] <= 6) ? 3 : 4];
 //[componentsToSubtract setWeekdayOrdinal:3]; //old way - not perfect

 NSDate *saturday = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:componentsToSubtract toDate:today options:0]; 
 NSDateComponents *components =
 [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit)
     fromDate: saturday];
 saturday = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

 NSLog([saturday description]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it.  My output after changing is: Date: 2010-11-01 05:00:00 GMT, Date: 2010-01-15 05:00:00 GMT.  It goes to the first month of the year.

Comment: See my edit. I have found the solution. (Parts from: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1)

Comment: Yes, this works.  I don't understand the subtraction though.  I'll keep reading...

Comment: The only thing that involves subtraction is the `setDay:` method. That line gets the number of days to Saturday.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work perfectly.  I'm trying to find the Saturday following the third Friday.  In this case, the output is Nov 20 (correct), Dec 18 (correct) and Jan 15 (incorrect - it should be 22).  Any ideas?

Comment: See my code edit. I'm starting to dislike Apple's way of handling dates.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you.  I was working on an if statement for -7 days, but your solution is much nicer. BTW, "I'm starting to dislike Apple's way of handling dates."  That was why I was scorned for posting "I hate..." above.  It's nice to know it's not only me. =)

Answer (score 4):

```
// Sunday = 1, Saturday = 7

int weekday = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate: date] weekday];
```